# Translate KEY to ZMK.LMK Thales 9000

Tags: hsm

i'm trying to decrypt a **KEY** send from host that encrypted under host **ZMK** and host **LMK** .
i use the Thales 9000 with command code **FA** to decrypt the **KEY** with **ZMK** that encypted under local **LMK**,
it do return with a decrypt key but the response code is **01** and the **KCV** not match with the 
host.

Thanks in advance.

[Process Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d618p.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure your Host and Switch are having the same ZMK check value.
2. Ensure your Host generates the ZPK in odd parity.

Comment: would the parity cause issues on the decryption ?

Comment: It would be better if you could post the actual HSM command data for your Host and Switch. If I can see the actual data it would be easier for me to identify the root cause.

Comment: this is the ZPK then encrypt under Host ZMK
77896CAB22699D66D9AF7918FFD0AE77 and KCV 726F00
but when decrypt under Switch ZMK the KCV is 7EE46D

Comment: How is the key 77896CAB22699D66D9AF7918FFD0AE77 generated?
What is your ZMK Clear Key?

Comment: is a random key and encrypted under Host ZMK, i dont have the ZMK clear key.
only have the ZMK.LMK(Host). for this is the GE command code to convert from ZMK.LMK(Host) to ZMK.LMK(Swithc) ?

i'm using FA to translate the ZPK

Comment: It's difficult to identify the root cause if you do not have the clear ZMK. You should try to confirm the ZMK at Host and Switch are having the same KCV using command BU.

Comment: yes. both side ZMK have the same KCV. but when use the ZMK after GE, it still hit 01 on FA. and the KCV is different

Comment: any command code is to decrypt those items encrypt under ZMK ?

Comment: Why you want to use GE?

Comment: A faster way is to get consultation with your local Thales provider. They should be able to help you directly.

Comment: GE to translate the ZMK.LMK(host) to ZMK.LMK(Switch)
tried to get the support from thales support. but they are too noob and not supportive.

Comment: do you have any ideas to get the clear ZMK ? now i have the encrypted ZMK.